# Displaying "Try again" UIAlertView during critical initialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

During the initialization of an app, I naturally have some critical things that have to be done to get the app running. For example, in this case I need to get the `AVCaptureDevice` pointer for the back camera.

So if it fails, (which it never should, but you never know), I want to display a `UIAlertView` with only one option, "Try again". When the user selects this, the app will try to get the `AVCaptureDevice` again.

The problem is that I need to wait for the user to press "Try again" before I continue, but `UIAlertView` is not modal.

If there was only one piece of code like this, I could potentially handle it with the `UIAlertViewDelegate` callback. But since there will be multiple critical pieces of initialization like this, I don't see how I could use the callback without things getting really messy.

Is there an elegant way to handle this?

Edit: Some code:

```
- (void)setup
{
    NSError *error = nil;

    // get all the video devices. (this should be the back camera and the front camera.)
    NSArray *videoDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    AVCaptureDevice *backVideoDevice;

    // find the back camera.
    do 
    {
        for (AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice in videoDevices)
        {
            if (videoDevice.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack)
            {
                backVideoDevice = videoDevice;

                break;
            }
        }

        if (backVideoDevice == nil)
        {
            // display UIAlertView???
        }

    } while (backVideoDevice == nil);

    // if no back camera was found, then we can't continue.

    AVCaptureDeviceInput *videoDeviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:backVideoDevice error:&error];

    AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutput = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput new];

    AVCaptureSession *captureSession = [AVCaptureSession new];

    if ([captureSession canAddInput:videoDeviceInput])
    {
        [captureSession addInput:videoDeviceInput];
    }

    if ([captureSession canAddOutput:stillImageOutput])
    {
        [captureSession addOutput:stillImageOutput];
    }

    // etc, etc.
}
```

Most of the steps will require checking if they succeeded, like the first one.

Comment: You could always have an unsigned char ivar that you set each time before showing alertview (0:n/a; 1;acquiring pointer to AVCaptureDevice; 2:reading defaults; 3:testing user's patience...) which would serve as some kind of state variable - you'd check it in your delegate method and you'd immidiately know what was the cause of showing alert in the first place.

Comment: @rokjarc Yeah, but the problem still is that I need to pause the initialization until the the `UIAlertView` is dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply have a initialization method like that :

```
- (void)initDevice {
  // If x device is not already initialized
  if (!_x) {
    _x = ...

    if (/* some error with _x initialization */) {
      // Show the alert view
      ...

      // Exit initialization
      return;
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

And call this method where you want to start the initialization and in the UIAlertViewDelegate callbacks.

If one of the variable is already initialized, it will not be initialized again due to the if statement.

You can also have a int variable called step that you set at each step passed and check the step variable to know where you need to continue the initialization.

Comment: I started to do this, but it won't work, because I have to pause the rest of the initialization until the the user presses "Try again".

Comment: simply exit the initialization method if an error occurs, i edited ly answer to reflect that.

Comment: But the problem is my overall initialization method, I need to pause it until the `initDevice` method succeeds.

Comment: So you need to do the same on the overall initialization method, return a BOOL in the initDevice method and check that when you call it in initOverall method and if it returns FALSE you quit also the initOverall method. Then, when the alert view is closed, call the initOverall method. initOverall needs to skip initialization of other objects if they are already initialized too like initDevice method.

Comment: If that can't be applied, please post some code you use for initialization.

Comment: That might be a way to do it, but it potentially would require adding some extra class variables just for initialization, and might be a little messy. I have posted some code.